# Unexpected field in POST data with a multiple choice fieldName

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

### What I have

```
foreach ($statuses as $key=>$value) {
    echo $this->Form->control('Filter.statuses['.$key.']', array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'value' => $key,
        'label' => $value,
    ));
}
```

### What I'm getting

> Unexpected field 'Filter.statuses[1' in POST data
>
> Unexpected field 'Filter.statuses[2' in POST data
>
> Unexpected field 'Filter.statuses[3' in POST data
>   ...

### What I have tried

```
$this->Form->unlockField('Filter.statuses');
$this->Form->unlockField('Filter.statuses[]');
```

If I remove the `Filter.` prefix, the errors are gone and I no longer need the `unlockField()` call.

### References

- [In cakephp 3 I got error Unexpected field in POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185112/in-cakephp-3-i-got-error-unexpected-field-in-post-data)
- [Unexpected field 'g-recaptcha-response' in POST data on CakePHP 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854069/unexpected-field-g-recaptcha-response-in-post-data-on-cakephp-3)
- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html

Comment: Keywords for googlebot: *square brackets*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to use brackets in the field name, the form helper doesn't support that. If you ever need an unconventional name that the form helper doesn't support, then use the `name` option to specify it, while passing a compatible field name to the `control()` method's first argument.

Use the dot syntax all the way:

```
echo $this->Form->control("Filter.statuses.$key", /* ... */);
```

That way the form helper will be able to secure the fields, and create proper HTML name attribute values like `Filter[statuses][1]`.